# How to call a Macro from Apache POI library in Java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have :

> - Macro named "process" that does all the processing work for my worksheets.
> - I want my Java code that uses Apache POI, to call this macro so that it can process the sheets for me.
> - How can I call a Macro in Apache POI in Java ?

**:: Note ::**

> - I am using `import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel` in Apache POI.
> - Please, give sample code. (I am new to Apache POI and Java itself.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. POI is a library to read/edit Office files, macros are a whole other beast. You would have to implement a Visual Basic for Applications Interpreter into POI to accomplish this. Macros that are already in your Excel workbook are preserved, but you cannot add new ones or call existing ones.

Comment: I already have the Macro in my file that I am editing. **I just want to execute the macro with Java POI !**

Comment: Please note that the current version of POI has support for regular Excel functions.

Comment: And if you want to execute a VBA Macro, you will either have to use OpenOffice or Microsoft Excel. You can bind to OpenOffice using their UNO interface, and to Microsoft Excel using COM (see JACOB for a COM java library).

Answer (score 6):

You can use other tool like [com4j](http://com4j.java.net). I created a POC just today and works like a charm. Just follow these steps:

1. Download the last version [here](http://java.net/projects/com4j/downloads)
2. Using [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build the sample: **samples\excel**
3. With the code generated by tlbimp (it is just a part of com4j), create a small app and write a code like:

   ```
   // Starts excel and open an existing workbook
   _Application app = ClassFactory.createApplication();
   app.setVisible(0, true);
   _Workbook wb = app.getWorkbooks().open("c:\\test.xlsx", null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
           null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0);

   // run a macro
   Variant macro = new Variant(Variant.Type.VT_BSTR);
   macro.set("my_macro");
   wb.getApplication().run(macro, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
           null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
           null, null, null, null);

   // Save the excel file and quit
   Variant saveBeforeExit = new Variant(Variant.Type.VT_BOOL);
   saveBeforeExit.set(1);
   wb.close(saveBeforeExit, Variant.getMissing(), Variant.getMissing(), 0);
   app.quit();
   ```
4. Further examples: [com4j tutorials](http://com4j.java.net/tutorial.html)

Comment: Is it real helpful? Does anyone confirm this?

Comment: damn, the number of null parameters gave me anxiety.

Answer (score 5):

I think, you can't.

> Macros
>
> Macros can not be created. However, reading and re-writing files
>   containing macros will safely preserve the macros.

[Apache POI Limitations](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html)

Comment: I already have the Macro in my file that I am editing.
**I just want to execute the macro with Java POI !**

Comment: Repeatedly stating your objective won't make it magically happen.

Answer (score 0):

One little hacky way to do this is to make your macros **run automatically when the workbook is opened.** This can be done from vba in ThisWorkbook module.
Then you can open excel with `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(filePath));` and with apache POI and FileInputStream just get the result of 'process' .