# External Excel lib for C# to run macros

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-macros

Do you know any external MS Excel library for C# (it should work without MS Office installed on machine) which has possibility to run macros?

It's possible to run it with "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel", but for that you need MS Office.

The scenario: I have MS Excel file template with macro. Adding part of the data programmatically to that template, running macro which was wrote to excel template, adding another part of data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

NPOI is a great tool and is Open Source:

[NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/releases/view/38113)

Comment: I haven't found any method to run macros with this library. If there exists a ability to do that, could you give me a hint?

Comment: NPOI does not support macros. See this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937777/how-to-call-a-macro-from-apache-poi-library-in-java)