# How to add multi-select dropdown in excel using poi

Tags: excel, apache-poi, libreoffice

I have an list of Strings (A,B,C,D,E) and i have added this list to cell using range and data validity in libre office. but it only selects one value at a time. I want something like if i select first D and then C output should be like D,C multi-select. I have already studied all the questions on stack overflow but i haven't found anything. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: i suggest you to go on this site : http://www.contextures.com/excel-data-validation-multiple.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I have already go through this link. What i am asking is it is possible to make this using poi library in java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POI doesn't support multi select drop down.

You can follow the below link.
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Validation

Answer (score 3):

As the provided link requires VBA scripting to do things, it is not possible to do this in POI currently as support for reading/adding VBA code is very limited. You could try to add it via the low-level API of POI, but would first find out where Excel stores the VBA code inside the .xlsx-file (it's actually a zip-file, so you can unzip it and take a look).

See the following for some pointers:

- [Macro support in POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html)
- [How to call a Macro from Apache POI library in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937777/how-to-call-a-macro-from-apache-poi-library-in-java)
- [How to call an Excel VBA Macro from Java Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789780/how-to-call-an-excel-vba-macro-from-java-code)