# How to edit a VB macro using Java

Tags: java, excel, excel-2010, vba

I have an excel where it has a macro defined in it. I am creating a Java program to perform some actions on that particular spreadsheet.
Here is the small snippet of the VB code

```
Sub ChangeAxis()
Attribute ChangeAxis.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = "a\n14"
 '
 'ChangeAxis Macro
 'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+a
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0.8
End Sub
```

Now, what i will have to do is, Open that spread Sheet, edit that macro with a specific Value( i.e 0.8 will be changed based on the scenarios of process), run the macro and then save the SpreadSheet.

Could someone suggest me how to edit the Macro using Java code.
Or is there a way i can run this Macro VBscript from my Java code directly?

Comment: Java or JavaScript - which one is it?

Comment: I am using Java 1.8

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just change the macro to receive a parameter of 0.8 (or whatever other value you want the macro to use)?  (E.g. `Sub ChangeAxis(Optional scaleValue As Double = 0.8)` (with, obviously, the `ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0.8` becoming `ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = scaleValue`)

Comment: Yes, I can consider this option as well. Can we pass a Value to Macro?

Comment: For e.g. you may find some advices there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937777/how-to-call-a-macro-from-apache-poi-library-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a Java to COM library like JACOB : http://danadler.com/jacob/

Comment: Could you pls share me code using JACOB, if you can.